# How can I plot a 3D line graph with a colormap

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

I want to try pyqtgraph instead of matplotlib for 3d line plot with colormap applied for data index.
Here is my code using matplotlib.

```
fig,ax= plt.subplots(figsize=(6,4), dpi=200, subplot_kw=dict(projection='3d'))
ax=ax.ravel()

x = ...
y = ...
z = ...
cn = colors.Normalize(0.0, len(x))

points = np.array([x, y, z]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 3)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)
lc = Line3DCollection(segments, cmap='jet', norm=cn)
lc.set_array(np.array(range(len(x))))
lc.set_linewidth(0.25)
ax.axis("off")
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax.set_ylim(y.min(), y.max())
ax.set_zlim(z.min(), z.max())

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

and I tried pyqtgraph.

```
cm = pg.colormap.getFromMatplotlib("jet")
c = np.arange(len(x))
color = cm.getLookupTable(0,1, nPts=len(c))

win = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget(show = True, size = (1000, 500))

ax = gl.GLLinePlotItem(pos=np.column_stack((x,y,z)), color = color, width=0.5)
view = gl.GLViewWidget()
view.addItem(axpg[i])

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

layout = QGridLayout()
win.setLayout(layout)

layout.addWidget(view, 0, 0)

app.instance().exec_()
```

It doesn't work well, partially drawn with white color which doesn't exist in colormap"jet".
How it works well?

I used cm.map instead of cm.getLookupTable but it doesn't work too.

Comment: Post a [mre]. Anyway, do like ```color = cm.getLookupTable(0,1, nPts=len(c)) / 256```.

Comment: Why not answer your own question?